# play sound based on int value

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple app where you can play sound based on int value you can increase by clicking a button,

for example I have a textbox with integer value inside it and I can increase the value of the integer inside the textbox or decrease it using two buttons, what I want to do is to play music if the integer value become more than 10, I tried to do this but the sound is not starting,

here is my code:

```
    int result;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gg);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


    if(result > 10 ) {
        mp.start();
    }
    else{

        mp.pause();
    }


    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          //  mp.start();
            result = result + 1;
            tv.setText(""+ result);

        }
    });


    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // mp.pause();
            result = result - 1;

            tv.setText(""+ result);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You shuold do your "play sound" task when `result` is more than 10. If you wirte
`start()` and `pause()` in `onCreate()` method, It will not be execute correctly.
The correct way it to write your `if` code block in both two `onClick` method

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          //  mp.start();
            result = result + 1;
            tv.setText(""+ result);
            if (result > 10 ) {
              mp.start();
            } else {
              mp.pause();
            }

        }
    });


    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // mp.pause();
            result = result - 1;

            tv.setText(""+ result);
            if (result > 10 ) {
              mp.start();
            } else {
              mp.pause();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the replay I tried your solution but still the sound doesn't play.